# Can we change the database code page after the database creation?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Can we change below configuration of DB2 Database after DB is created.

```
 Database territory                                      = US
 Database code page                                      = 1208
 Database code set                                       = UTF-8
 Database country/region code                            = 1
```

Can some one give me the steps to do.

Comment: You may also wish to see my answer on this question for tactics about how to change this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36686/dutch-characters-in-db2-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the database code set after creation.